# i want to print my sorted list in python but it gives me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def srt(number):
  list=[]
  list=sorted(number)
  return list


print srt([5,2,4,1,3])
```

It gives an error:

> invalid syntax: print **srt**([5,2,4,1,3])

Comment: I think the error is clear so I add some remarks concerning the other code. You don't need `list=[]` because you overwrite `list` in the next line anyway. And you shouldn't call a variable `list` because you overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). The whole function body could be reduced to `return sorted(number)`.

Comment: @Matthias or even just `srt = sorted`

Answer (score 4):

```
def srt(number):
    my_list=[]
    my_list=sorted(number)
    return my_list

print (srt([5,2,4,1,3]))
```

you forgot the () for print

Comment: but this is running fine in python 2

Comment: Also, both OP and @Chrisvdberge please do not use `list` as the variable. Use `my_list` or `list1` instead. Anything but `list`.

Comment: @Shrey print is changed across python2 and python3

Comment: @YogeshSudheerModak you are right, edited the answer accordingly :)

Comment: @Shrey Concerning the difference between Python 2 and Python 3. Are you aware that support for Python 2 will stop this year?